# Finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $4\times 4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors(and generalized eigenvectors) of the following matrix.

$$\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix} -1&0&0&0\\ 5&-2&0&0\\ 0&3&1&0\\ 2&0&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Okay so when I did the work I got my eigenvalues to be $\lambda= \{1,-1,-2\}$. I'm struggling with the eigenvectors. When I tried doing it for $\lambda=-1$ I got something along the lines of

$$0\vec{v}_1+0\vec{v}_{2}+0\vec{v}_3+0\vec{v}_4 = 0$$

$$5\vec{v}_1+-1\vec{v}_{2}+0\vec{v}_3+0\vec{v}_4 = 0$$

$$0\vec{v}_1+3\vec{v}_{2}+2\vec{v}_3+0\vec{v}_4 = 0$$

$$2\vec{v}_1+0\vec{v}_{2}+1\vec{v}_3+2\vec{v}_4 = 0$$

But this way I couldn't get a solid number for my vectors. Some direction on this would be great. I'm really stuck on the vectors part.

Comment: Keep going, diagonalizing the system you have with $\lambda = -1$.  You know there's going to be a zero row (that's what eigenvalues are for).  But you need to find a vector (or vectors) spanning the eigenspace and you do that via solving the deficient system you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read off the eigenvector directly from the matrix you have.
The only thing you need is that the matrix is in some triangular form.

For example for $\lambda=-1$ we have:
$$(A-\lambda I)\vec v = (A + I)\vec v = \vec 0$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 &  &  &  \\
5 & -1 &  &  \\
0 & 3 & 2 & \\
2 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
w \\ x \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

We can choose our own scaling factor, which means that we have a free choice for some non-zero element.
Let's try $w=1$, meaning the first line checks out.

Then, from the second line we can conclude that $5w - x = 0$, so $x=5$.

From the 3rd line we get that $3x+2y=0$, so $y=-7.5$.

Finally, from the 4th line we get that $2w + y + 2z = 0$, so $z = 2.75$.

In other words:
$$\vec v = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 5 \\ -7.5 \\ 2.75
\end{pmatrix}$$

To get nice round numbers, we can scale it up by a factor of 4 and get:
$$\vec v = \begin{pmatrix}
4 \\ 20 \\ -30 \\ 11
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

For the eigenvalue, $\lambda_1 = -1$, we get the RREF of $[A - \lambda_1 I]v_1 = [A + I]v_1 = 0$ as:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{4}{11} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{20}{11} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{30}{11} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)v_1 = 0$$

This gives us an eigenvector of $v_1 = (4, 20, -30, 11)$.

**Update 1**

The steps to do that RREF are:

- Do row swaps to move the all zeros row to be the bottom row.
- $R_3 = R_3 - \dfrac{2}{5}R_1$ (this is read, replace row $3$ by row three minus $2/5$ row 1.
- $R_3 = 5 R_3$ (multiply $R_3$ by $5$)
- $R_3 = R_3 - \dfrac{2}{3}R_2$
- $R_3 = 3 R_3$
- $R_3 = R_3/11$
- $R_2 = R_2 - 2 R_3$
- $R_2 = R_2/3$
- $R_1 = R_1 + R_2$
- $R_1 = R_1/5$

**Update 2**

For the eigenvalue, $\lambda_2 = -2$, we have a RREF for $[A+2I]v_2 = 0$ as:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -3 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)v_2 = 0$$

In this case, we choose $v_2 = (0, 3, -3, 1)$.

**Update 3**

For the double eigenvalue, we get one independent eigenvector and have to find a second generalized one. That process is (it could change to chaining in the worst cases):

- Find $[A - \lambda_3 I]v_3 = [A - I]v_3 = 0$ for $v-3$.
- Solve $[A-I]v_4 = v_3$ for $v_4$.

You should get:

$$v_3 = (0, 0, 0, 1), v_4 = (0, 0, 1, 0)$$

Comment: ok so what you did here you switched the first and last row so the the last row would be all zeros right? N you got those values by using the calculator? I pretty much tried that by hand n got the same values too. So the answer for the vector you got instead of 11 shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: It probably would because this is the part I got stuck in

Comment: Oh ok yes I understand that process. What I'm more confused by is the answer you got. How did the last vector become 11? Isn't it a zero? I tried the same idea for $\lambda=-2$ and I got $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&1&0\\ 0&0&\frac{1}{3}&1\\ 0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$. So does that mean my vectors are $(0,1,1/3,0)$? Mainly I'm confused by that.

Comment: Oh ok yea that makes a lot of sense. So if you look at what I got for $\lambda=-2$ are my vectors then $=(0,-1,1,-1/3)$? Did I do that right?

Comment: Oh ok so then $=(0,-3,3,-1)$ is the same thing

Comment: Oh right yea cuz I got $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}$. How do I do that or do you know where I can look at something like that being done?

Comment: Right. Yes got it. Thank you so much :).

Answer (score 0):

Look up computing reduced row echelon form for finding the kernel of a matrix. This will give you the eigenvector for each eigenvalue because when you plug in the eigenvalue you know that the eigenvector is in the kernel of the resulting matrix.